# Changing values in a column of a Dataset using a Do loop

Tags: dataset

I'm trying to use "Do" to change the entries in a column of a dataset using two adjacent columns. When I simply assign i and execute the lin for each value of i, it works but when I enclose it in Do, the Dataset becomes null.

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
sample5 =Do[ReplacePart[sample4, {i, "GeoPosition"} ->
GeoPosition[{sample4[i, "Latitude"], 
sample4[i, "Longitude"]}]], {i, Length[sample4]}]
```

The trial Dataset is:

```
Dataset[{<|"Facility Name" -> "Stanford Health Care", "Latitude" -> 37.4330139, "Longitude" -> -122.1758423,"GeoPosition" -> "GeoPosition"|>, <|"Facility Name" ->  "California Pacific Medical Center - California West Campus \  Hospital", "Latitude" -> 37.7861157, "Longitude" -> -122.4560595,"GeoPosition" -> "GeoPosition"|>} ]
```

Mathematica 11.3 on Mac Os Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use `Do`.  Try `Table` instead.

Comment: There are **plenty** of good reasons to use `Do` (haven't checked if this is one of them)

Comment: Can Table be used to modify a Dataset and still result in a Dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that

```
ReplacePart[ sample4, rules]
```

does not modify `sample4`, but in fact returns a new `Dataset` with the desired replacement.

The reason that your `example5` is `Null` is because that is what `Do` returns.  `Do` is a wonderful function, but it won't return anything (it just *does* something).

Minimal modification to your code:

```
sample5 = sample4;
Do[
    sample5 = ReplacePart[
        sample5,
        {i, "GeoPosition"} -> GeoPosition[{sample5[i, "Latitude"], sample5[i, "Longitude"]}]
    ],
    {i, Length @ sample4}
]
```

For this particular use case, you don't need to loop at all, you can do it all in one `ReplacePart` command:

```
ReplacePart[sample4,
    {i_, "GeoPosition"} :> GeoPosition[{sample4[i, "Latitude"], sample4[i, "Longitude"]}]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

For a functional approach you may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) directly or implicitly with `Dataset`.  Taking `sample4` as in OP then

direct use with,

```
Query[All, <|#, "GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@{#["Latitude"], #["Longitude"]}|> &]@sample4
```

and implicit use with `Slot` syntax sugar

```
sample4[All, <|#, "GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@{#Latitude, #Longitude}|> &]
```

Both of the above give

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.